# plot.gam from mgcv with all.terms = TRUE within a function

Tags: r, mgcv

I want to write a function that estimates a `gam` with factor variables and plots the result of all variables, including the factor variables. However, the `plot` function from the mgcv-package produces an error. Why does this error occur and how can I solve it?

```
library(mgcv)
plot_model <- function(x){
  agam <- gam(mean ~ s(bla) + bla2, data=x)
  plot(agam, pages=1, all.terms = TRUE)
   # here Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
}
bla <- data.frame(bla=rnorm(20), bla2=sample(letters[1:4], size=20, replace=T), 
                  mean=sample(20))
plot_model(bla)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `x` needs to be declared in the local environment so that `plot.gam` can use it for the plot. You can make it work as follows:

```
library(mgcv)
plot_model <- function(y){
  data <- y
  agam <- mgcv::gam(mean ~ s(bla) + bla2, data=data)
  mgcv::plot.gam(x = agam, pages=1, all.terms = TRUE)
  # here Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
}
dat <- data.frame(bla=rnorm(20), bla2=sample(letters[1:4], size=20, replace=T), 
                  mean=sample(20))
plot_model(dat)
```

Comment: It works if I call the data set data, but it doesn't work if I call it x or x2. Any idea why it is like that? If I call it data, it also works, when I omit the first line (data <- y).

Comment: mgcv does not coerce characters to factors. You need to feed it factor variables. Also, I would probably use `agam <- eval(bquote(mgcv::gam(mean ~ s(bla) + bla2, data=.(y))))`.

Comment: data.frame does the conversion of bla2 to factor, so bla2 is already of class factor. Your version works for me, too. Could you explain what it does (differently)?

Comment: I get an error when running this: 
`Error in eval(term, data, enclos = pf) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'`